# sort 3D array by the sum of the second value

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to sort a 3D array and having little success. I have read various methods on how this is done for two dimensions, but I can't seem to scale it up.

I have an array like:

```
[[[0, 25], [1, 20], [2, 80], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
[[0, 80], [0, 20], [1, 25], [1, 40], [2, 99], [0, 0]], 
[[0, 99], [1, 40], [2, 80], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

I want this to be sorted by the sum of the second value.
The criteria that I use to order is the sum of the second value.
E.g:

```
 25+20+80 = 125
 80+20+25+40+99 = 264
 99+40+80 = 219
```

so:

```
 [[[0, 80], [0, 20], [1, 25], [1, 40], [2, 99], [0, 0]], 
 [[0, 99], [1, 40], [2, 80], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], 
 [[0, 25], [1, 20], [2, 80], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: The second value of what? Each list?

Comment: Second array that you have specified doesn't seem sorted in any way. If yes please explain what kind of exact sorting has been done on the Second array ?

Comment: You can't sort multidimensional data as is. You need a mapping to one dimension and define your criteria for sorting. For example, vector (2,3) has no sorting relation with (3,1), but if you map it to the norm (one dimension) then you can sort in some way.

Comment: You may do it as follows:  sorted(array[::-1], key=lambda x: x[2])

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you need. Suppose your array is stored in `a`.

```
>>> a
Out[19]: 
array([[[ 0, 25],
        [ 1, 20],
        [ 2, 80],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 0, 80],
        [ 0, 20],
        [ 1, 25],
        [ 1, 40],
        [ 2, 99],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 0, 99],
        [ 1, 40],
        [ 2, 80],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

`a[:, :, 1]` accesses the second element of the innermost dimension, so you can sum over this (on the horizontal axis, i.e. axis=1) to get the values you need for sorting:

```
>>> a[:, :, 1]
Out[20]: 
array([[25, 20, 80,  0,  0,  0],
       [80, 20, 25, 40, 99,  0],
       [99, 40, 80,  0,  0,  0]])
>>> b = np.sum(a[:, :, 1], axis=1)
>>> b
Out[21]: array([125, 264, 219])
```

Use `np.argsort` to get the sorted indices, rather than the sorted array:

```
>>> i = np.argsort(b)[::-1] # Reverse the array for descending order
>>> i
Out[23]: array([1, 2, 0])
```

Finally, access your array using the indices, as desired:

```
>>> a[i, :, :]
Out[25]: 
array([[[ 0, 80],
        [ 0, 20],
        [ 1, 25],
        [ 1, 40],
        [ 2, 99],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 0, 99],
        [ 1, 40],
        [ 2, 80],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 0, 25],
        [ 1, 20],
        [ 2, 80],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

Hope this helps!