# How to handle large files in python?

Tags: arrays, list, file, python-3.x, numpy

I am new in python. I have asked another question [How to arrange three lists in such a way that the sum of corresponding elements if greater then appear first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654895/how-to-arrange-three-lists-in-such-a-way-that-the-sum-of-corresponding-elements) Now the problem is following:

I am working with a large text file, in which there are 419040 rows and 6 columns containing floats. Among them I am taking first 3 columns to generate those three lists. So the lists I am actually working with has 419040 entries in each. While I was running the python code to extract the three columns into three lists the python shell was not responding, I suspected the large number of entries for this, I used this code:

```
file=open("file_location","r")
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
for lines in file:
    x=lines.split(" ")
    a.append(float(x[0]))
    b.append(float(x[1]))
    c.append(float(x[2]))
```

Note: for small file this code was running perfectly.
To avoid this problem I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = []
b = []
c = []
a,b,c = np.genfromtxt('file_location',usecols = [0,1,2], unpack=True)
```

So when I am running the code given in answers to my previous question the same problem is happening. So what will be the corresponding code using numpy? Or, any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use numpy, then I suggest using `ndarray`s, rather than lists. You can use `loadtxt` since you don't have to handle missing data. I assume it'll be faster.

```
a = np.loadtxt('file.txt', usecols=(0, 1, 2))
```

`a` is now a two-dimensional array, stored as an `np.ndarray` datatype. It should look like:

```
>>> a
array([[  1,  20, 400],
       [  5,  30, 500],
       [  3,  50, 100],
       [  2,  40, 300],
       [  4,  10, 200]])
```

However, you now need to re-do what you did in the previous question, but using numpy arrays rather than lists. This can be easily achieved like so:

```
>>> b = a.sum(axis=1)
>>> b
Out[21]: array([535, 421, 342, 214, 153])
>>> i = np.argsort(b)[::-1]
>>> i
Out[26]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[i, :]
Out[27]: 
array([[  5,  30, 500],
       [  1,  20, 400],
       [  2,  40, 300],
       [  4,  10, 200],
       [  3,  50, 100]])
```

The steps involved are described in a little greater detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644870/sort-3d-array-by-the-sum-of-the-second-value/30650872#30650872).